# Best Way To Store Multiple Flags In Database

Tags: database-design

I have a web-based application that notifies users of activity on the site via email. Users can choose which kinds of notifcations they want to receive. So far there are about 10 different options (each one is a true/false).

I'm currently storing this in one varchar field as a 0 or 1 separated by commas. For example:
1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0

This works but it's difficult to add new notification flags and keep track of which flag belongs to which notification. Is there an accepted standard for doing this? I was thinking of adding another table with a column for each notification type. Then I can add new columns if I need, but I'm not sure how efficient this is.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I would use two tables.  One table would store the user data and the other the notifications that they subscribe to.  The second table would look something like this:

```
create table notifications (
   user_id int,
   notification_type int
);
```

I'd make a FK relationship between user_id and the user's id in the users table with a cascade on delete.  Use both the user_id and notification_type as the primary key.  To check if a user wants a particular notification simply do a join between the two tables and select rows where the notification_type matches the one in question.  If the result set is non-empty the user wants the notification.

Adding new notifications becomes trivial (as does deleting).  Simply add (delete) a new type value and let users choose to accept it or not.  If you wanted to keep the notification types in a table to manage via the application that would work, too, but it would be a little more complex.

Comment: This seems the best solution by far IMO. Storing them all in one column is not very extensible. And storing them as bool fields in a table means you have to add a new field every time there is a new notification type.

Comment: The would work well, particularly if you want to be able to scan the notification types.

Comment: normalization is great for extensibility, but it does suffer a bit on performance.

Comment: The FK relationship should induce an index on the user_id in the second table, making this an index join which should limit the impact on performance.

Comment: Flexibility first. Optimize for performance, without sacrificing too much flexibility, later - and only when you know that you have to. Do it the way this answer suggests.

Answer (score 5):

Using MySQL?

Then, SET datatype is the answer.

"The MySQL SET datatype is stored as an integer value within the MySQL tables, and occupies from one to eight bytes, depending on the number of elements available."
- http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql-set-datatype.html"

Answer (score 3):

I would use 10 different bit or bool fields.  But if your going to do it in one field, you can use a bitmap 0x1111111111 as a big integer or a text field without the comma.  I've worked on different applications, using all those techniques. But I'd actually just go with the multiple fields.  It will be a lot easier to do select statements on.

Comment: What are reasons to use on field only? I've seen that MediaWiki does this.

Answer (score 2):

If you do decided to use a bit field like @stephenbayer mentioned you can always use a view on the table to make it easier for developers to use. This then means that you still have the space savings of the bit field and the ease of use of separate columns per field and while avoiding having to parse the column.

As mentioned the separate table is an excellent option if you want your solution to be more extensible. The only downside is slightly increased complexity.

This is the trade off. If you want something that is really easy to implement and is fast consider the bit field. If you want something that is easier to extend and maintain at the cost of slightly more complexity then by all means go for the separate table. If the votes tell you anything you probably want to follow the separate table implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I'd expect that letting the DB manage it by using Bool columns would be better. I seem to recall that some systems will pack bools to bits (null might mess that up). To avoid clutter, you might make it a separate table.

(I'm no DBA)

*Edit: slaps head "I just suggested exactly what you are thing of" :b*